# How to know where to save model method

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple question.
Suppose products with associtaed recommandations. I'd like to get a product recommandation then it's a simple model method (i.e: get_product_recommandation()) but I do not know to put it. In my recommandations models.py or in models.py in the product folder ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd put it in your models.py in the product app like:

```
Class Product(models.Model):

    ...

    def get_product_recommandation(self):
        return self.recommendation_set.all()  #  or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make custom querysets or manger to put database query realted function. put model update function in model file.